# Find a relation between arguments of euclidian algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory, euclidean-algorithm

Suppose $(a,b)$ are arguments of the euclidian algorithm, and $a>b$. Let's call $a_i$, $b_i$ their values on the i-th step of computation (We shall put $a$, $b$ = $a_0$,$b_0$):

$$
\begin{matrix}
a_0 = & q_0 \cdot b_0 + r_0 \\
a_1 = & q_1 \cdot b_1 + r_1 \\
a_2 = & q_2 \cdot b_2 + r_2 \\
\dots 
\end{matrix}
$$

Then, given that $a$ have decreased by the factor 5 after two steps of euclidian algorithm, find the relation $\frac {a_2} {b_2}$ provided that $b_2$ is non-zero.

Playing around the task I was unable to come up with $(a,b)$ pair which would comply to the provided conditions, namely the $b_2$ always turned into zero.
Then I tried to write it in as a set of equations: 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
5x & = q_0\ \cdot\ b  + x \\
b & = q_1\ \cdot\ x  + r_1 \\
x & = q_2\ \cdot\ r_1  + 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$ 
So for the answer it is supposedly sufficient to find $q_2$, yet I am stuck.

**Edit**
Actually, I solved it, taking arbitrary $q_2=3$, $r_1=2$ and working it up. Hence answer is $3$, but it seem to be not unique answer. If I will be able to reach author and get some context on a problem, I will comment later.

Comment: You forgot to define $\,a_2,\,b_2\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque I have edited. Sorry, the original formulation seemed less cryptic to me

Comment: That's still rather imprecise. I still can't uniquely infer what $\,a_2, b_2\,$ are (keep in mind that are many ways to present / notate the Euclidean algorithm).

Comment: @BillDubuque I expanded it some more, hopefully, it helped.